# Functions on property sheet macros (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio

On [Property sheet macro PlatformShortName inconsistent between Win32 and x64 versions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537461/property-sheet-macro-platformshortname-inconsistent-between-win32-and-x64-versions) I learned that when editing e.g. project properties, you can use functions on Visual Studio macros to modify their value like this:

```
$(PlatformShortName.Replace("amd", "x"))
```

The above works, but I wasn't able to find any hints regarding this feature in Microsoft's  documentation. Can anyone give me a hint if there are any other functions in addition to Replace() available and where I can find a list or some documentation of it? For example I would like to have something that can change a value to all uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: By trying out some functions like `ToUpper` and `Trim` or properties like `Length` one can assume VS treats them as .NET string objects

Comment: Found a nice [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/04/02/msbuild-property-functions.aspx) by the VS Engineering Team